# How to pass Functional component as argument to a function

Tags: reactjs

Don't know whether it is possible with functional component or not, just want to know how to pass whole functional component as argument to function, just same as done in class component below:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { signUpApi } from './api/AllApi'
    export class SignUpComponent extends Component {
        render() {
            handleClick = (e) => {
    // with this keyword as argument complete class component can be accessed in this function as argument
                signUpApi(this, [argument2], [argument3])
            }
            return (
                <div>
                    {/* 
                    Class component here
                    */}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default SignUpComponent
```

How to pass React functional component as argument to a function?

Comment: Maybe just like how you pass normal elements to JS functions.

Comment: `signUpApi(this` There's no `this` in function components, so there isn't anything exactly equivalent to this code. What does `signUpApi` do with the instance of the component?

Comment: @NicholasTower 
 signUpApi function perform async api call with the instances of the component, some props and state are being used in this API from the component,
Trying to perform all API calls in diffrent file.
I was searching for the same with hooks what alreadyb done in class component.

Thanks a lot

Comment: `some props and state are being used in this API from the component` Perhaps you should modify `signUpApi` so that you pass in the relevant props and state, not the entire component instance.